# Black background while ScrollView loads

Tags: android, android-activity, background, scrollview, background-color

I have a `ScrollView` in an activity that contains a `WebView` and it looks like the ScrollView takes a little bit to load showing a black background until it has loaded. If I try and put a Layout behind the `ScrollView` with a white background then the fade that indicates that you can scroll turns white too.

I've tired putting a background colour on layouts both within and outside the scroll view; one affects the scrolling fade and the other doesn't load leaving the black space, same with setting the colour on the scroll view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it takes time for the ScrollView to load, it probably means that you have some processing that can be done in background. You may want to move the processing to a background thread (using AsyncTask) and update the GUI in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: The `WebView` is loading a template HTML file from disc and populating it with `String.format(template, arg1, arg2)` is that likely to be a cause?

Comment: This might be the cause since file operation takes some time. you can easily measure it using currentTimeMillis( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html ) before and after the processing